# Scrapy safe way to extract items

Tags: python, scrapy, scrape

What's is the best safe way to extract items information from pages?
I mean, sometimes a item may be missing in the page and you'll end up breaking the crawler.

Look this example:

```
    for cotacao in tabela_cotacoes:
        citem = CotacaoItem()
        citem['name'] = cotacao.select("td[4]/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['symbol'] = cotacao.select("td/a/b/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['current'] = cotacao.select("td[6]/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['last_neg'] = cotacao.select("td[7]/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['oscillation'] = cotacao.select("td[8]/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['openning'] = cotacao.select("td[9]/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['close'] = cotacao.select("td[10]/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['maximum'] = cotacao.select("td[11]/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['minimun'] = cotacao.select("td[12]/text()").extract()[0]
        citem['volume'] = cotacao.select("td[13]/text()").extract()[0]
```

If some item is missing in the page, .extract() will return [] and calling [0] on them will raise an exception (out of range).

So the question is, what is the best way/approach to deal with it this.

Comment: Separate issue, but I would make a parallel list instead of typing (or copying) all the functions out 10 times. `Fields = ['name','current','last_neg'...]; Nums = [4,6,7...]` them loop through `for MyField, MyNum in zip(Fields,Nums): citem[MyField] = cotacao...[MyNum]...` Then you can do it just with one loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a little helper function:

```
def extractor(xpathselector, selector):
    """
    Helper function that extract info from xpathselector object
    using the selector constrains.
    """
    val = xpathselector.select(selector).extract()
    return val[0] if val else None
```

And use it like this:

```
citem['name'] = extractor(cotacao, "td[4]/text()")
```

Return an appropriate value to indicate that a `citem` wasn't found. In my code I returned `None`, change it if necessary (for example, return `''` if it makes sense).

Comment: I was afraid that I'd have to make the verification on each line and be too verbose. Using a helper function keep it clean, that's nice. It's the solution you use in your projects? Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Medeiros yes, that's right. I always use lots of little helper procedures for validation, etc. i don't like to keep things too verbose :)

Comment: Sure, I always way a bit before accept because the discussion can grow and need adapt the question and/or answer. Everybody wins. :)

Comment: For example, I just realized that you need to pass cotacao as argument in order to be a generalized helper function.

Comment: @Medeiros of course, it makes sense to pass `cotacao` around as a parameter, I edited my answer, feel free to rename the parameter to something more meaningful - I don't speak Portuguese :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38046/discussion-between-medeiros-and-oscar-lopez)